# Keep div fixed only inside another div and dont let it go outside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div element inside another div called `fixed`. What I want is to keep div `fixed` scrollable. Here is a CSS for fixed div:

```
#fixed
{
    overflow:scroll;
    position:fixed;
    height:450px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
    <form name="myForm" class="formcss" method="POST" action="create3.php" id="reportform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<img src="img/stuff.png" style="margin-left:35%; width:320px;">
    <div class="large-3 columns" style="margin-top:1.5%;" id="fixed">
        <label>Choose username</label>
        <input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />

        <select>
          <option disabled selected>Sort By</option>
          <option value="new">Free Artists</option>
          <option value="asc">Artists with 1 project</option>
          <option value="desc">Artists with 1+ projects</option>
        </select>

        <input type='checkbox' value="ft" onclick="getUsers('sort',this.value)">FT</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value="ct" onclick="getUsers('sort',this.value)">CT</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value="ap" onclick="getUsers('sort',this.value)">AP</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value="ct3" onclick="getUsers('sort',this.value)">CT-3</input>
        <input type='checkbox' value="ct6" onclick="getUsers('sort',this.value)">CT-6</input>           

        <div id="myAccordion">
        <?php //for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
              //{
                //echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
                echo "<h3>Names</h3>";
                echo '<ul class="source">'; 
                $sql = "SELECT username FROM user ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);       
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {  
                        $name= $row["username"];    
                        echo"<li class='item'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$name."</li>";
                    }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }                       
                echo '</ul>';                   
            //}
        ?>  
        </div>
    </div>

        <label>Project <?php echo $code?></label>
        <div class="rowone">
            <div class="projLeader">
            <label>Captain:</label>
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
                    <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" required/>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
            <label>Information:</label>
                <ol>
                    <li class="totalinfo">Total: 0.</li>
                    <li class="leaderinfo">Process Leaders: 0.</li>
                    <li class="checkerinfo">Process Checkers: 0.</li>
                    <li class="staffinfo">Process Artists: 0.</li>
                </ol>
            </div>                  
            <div class="projChecker">
            <label>Coordinator:</label>
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder" name="projChecker"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
                    <?php 
                            //echo '<li class="dropClass" name="projChecker"> <span class="closer">x</span>'.$_SESSION['projChecker'].'</li>';
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="projChecker" class="hiddenListInput2" required/>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowtwo">
        <?php 
            for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
            {   
                echo "<div class='proc'> <pre>";
                echo "<h6 >Process: ".$proc[$y]."      "   ;
                echo "People required: ".$num[$y].".      ";    
                echo "<span class='assigned' name='assigned[]' >People Assigned: 0. </span>    <input class='unchecked' id='unchecked' type='hidden' name='link[]' value='0'/><input class='checked' id='checked' type='checkbox' name='link[]' value='1'><i title='Activate Process' class='fi-link'></i>Link Process</input></h6></pre>";
        ?>

            <div class="procLeader">
            <label>Leader:</label>  
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="procChecker">
            <label>Checker:</label>
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding" >Drop Here</div></li>
                </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="procStaff"> 
            <label>Artist:</label>
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
                </ol>
            </div>  
            <!--<div class="small-8 large-8 columns" style="margin-left: 15%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Studio:  <small id="small">*</small>         
                    <div class="multiselect">               
                        <div class="selectBox">                 
                            <select onclick="showCheckboxes()"  class="input input1 name">
                                <option>-- Select an option --</option>         
                            </select>
                            <div class="overSelect"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="scrollable" id="checkboxes">    
                        <?php 
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultStudio))
                            {
                                $row[0] = cleanOutputData($row[0]);

                                if(isset($studio))
                                {
                                    foreach($studio as $code)
                                    {
                                        if($row[0] == $code)
                                        {
                                            $match = 1;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        else
                                            $match = 0;
                                    }
                                }                       
                        ?>  
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
                                <label style="height: 37px; width:70%; float:left;" >
                                <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" style="margin-left:5%; width:15%;" name='studio[]' id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" /><?php echo $row[0] ?>
                                </label>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        ?>      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>              
            </div>-->
            <div class="small-8 large-8 columns" style="margin-left: 25%;">
            <table class="multiselect">
                <tr><td><label>Studio:</label>  </td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td >
                    <select  class="input input1 name">
                        <option>       -- Select Studio --</option>
                        <?php echo $studio ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input id="img" class='AddNew' type="image" src="img/add.png" alt="Submit" onClick="return false;"></td>
                <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>



        <?php       
                echo "</div>";                      
            }
        ?>  
        </div>      
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
                <input type = "submit" style="margin-left:300px; width:150px;" id="savebutton" name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Project" onclick="userSubmitted = true;"/>         
                </div>
        </div>              
    <div class="output1"></div>             
    <div class="output2" ></div>    
    <div class="output3"></div>                 
    </div>      
</fieldset>
</form>
```

What I [got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvou4.jpg) when i use `position: fixed`. But I want it to stay inside white area when I scroll down. I want it to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QErLy.jpg). How it can be achieved?

### EDIT

after proposed solutions I edited code like that:

```
.formcss{
  position: relative;
  margin-left:65px;
  margin-right:470px;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:90%;
}

#fixed
{
  overflow:scroll;
  position: absolute;
  height:450px;
}
```

Comment: can you add your html code?

Comment: @dreamhunter added

Comment: where is `.formcss` in your HTML?

Comment: @wscourge I added it in code

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed;` **makes element's position relative to the browser window** (so it scrolls along with it), **not any other DOM element**. So in your case it should be something like:

```
#fixed
{
   overflow:scroll;
   position:fixed;
   left: 1rem; // your distance from left edge of the window
   top: 1rem; // your distance from top edge of the window
   height:450px;
}
```

If what you want to achieve is to make your `#fixed` **attached to the specific area** of your website and **not the window**, you what you are looking for is `position: absolute;` on the `#fixed` and `position: relative;` on it's parent, like:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
#fixed { 
  overflow:scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem; // your distance from top edge of the parent
  left: 1rem; // your distance from left edge of the parent
  height:450px;
}
```

You can always [play around](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed) with positions to understand them better.

**EDIT**

Compare [fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/1pwq6koo/) with [absolute](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/x0pehq6s/). Only difference between those two examples is second line of CSS section: `position`.

I couldn't recreate this example on the code provided as it contains many bugs
(like closing `<input></input>`), so make sure to [validate](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) it.

I hope you can achieve your desired effect following examples of code I provided for both cases.

Comment: And what exactly happens? And which of two mentioned is your case, position `fixed` or `absolute`?

Comment: I used position `absolute` and nothing happened. `#fixed` just stayed on the same place

Comment: Could you edit your code accordingly so we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position: fixed` use `position: absolute` and `position: relative` on parent, that way element will be *fixed* to parent element position.

```js
// !ONLY FOR DEMO!
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').animate({
    left: '80%',
    top: '80%',
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.wrapper div {
  position: relative;
  background: #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper div:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
  content: '-^-';
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [preview](http://jsbin.com/dekaxi/edit?html,css,output)

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color: #252525;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #fff5f1;
}
```